# sfdx execute command not executing the apxc file .."File not found at the specified path:" error

Tags: apex, sfdx-error

i am trying to execute filename.apxc file using sfdx.

`sfdx force:apex:execute -u dev -f filename.apxc`

it throwing the error

> File not found at the specified path:

Comment: Well, where _is_ the file? Can you show us your project's directory structure and why you believe this error isn't correct, by [edit]ing your post?

Comment: how to see project directory from the URL

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i know only the URL ...directory path how to get from URL

Comment: I don't understand how a URL relates to your question, so I'll urge you again to [edit] your post and provide _all_ the context, including detailed reproduction steps and optionally screenshots, to help any community member understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`force:apex:execute` must be a file *on your computer*. You'll need to download the file if you want to execute it with this command.